# Google maps Places Picker for iOS - GMSPlacePicker in Swift appearing but disappears when animation ends

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to convert the simple GMSPlacePicker example to Swift

but the Picker appears but then disappears immediately as soon as the transition from Right to left completes.

```
    //  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonPlacesPicker_TouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var southWestSydney : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.8659, 151.1953)
        var northEastSydney : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.8645, 151.1969)

        var sydneyBounds : GMSCoordinateBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWestSydney, coordinate:northEastSydney)

        //var config : GMSPlacePickerConfig = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport:sydneyBounds)
        var config : GMSPlacePickerConfig = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport:nil)

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        var placePicker : GMSPlacePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

        //typealias GMSPlaceResultCallback = (GMSPlace?, NSError?) -> Void

        var error: NSError? = nil
        var gmsPlace: GMSPlace? = nil

        placePicker.pickPlaceWithCallback(){
            (gmsPlace, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error{
                println("error:\(error)")
            }else{
                if let gmsPlace = gmsPlace{
                    if let formattedAddress = gmsPlace.formattedAddress{
                        println("formattedAddress:\r\(formattedAddress)")
                    }else{
                        println("gmsPlace.formattedAddress is nil")
                    }

                }else{
                    println("gmsPlace is nil")
                }

                println("info")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app has asked for Location sucessfully

I have a bridging header to Google Maps.

I didnt use cocoa pods to install the framework

but I've used the framework in Obj-C before

so just dragged the GoogleMaps.framework to project 
and the internal resources bundle

I added all the following from previous tutorials and linker errors:

[image]

When I run it I can see sydney in the pickers maps.

It transitions from right side fo the screen to the left.

When it reaches the left it disappears

I added Reveal app and I cant see the picker view offline.

My GMS services api key is correct as its one I used in obj-c app to show Places Picker.

Bundle id is correct.

My Swift knowledge is "I think I know it. I probably don't"

any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should retain the reference to your GMSPlacePicker. Make it a property instead of local variable.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED made it an ivar...DOH!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var placePicker : GMSPlacePicker?

    @IBAction func buttonPlacesPicker_TouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback(){

        ...
```

Comment: You should give the answer to FiRiN above since he's the one who provided it for you.